Vectors with highest weight in irreducible Module
I am currently reading Lie Algebras and Representation Theory from Andreas Cap and there is one detail (Page 61) which I simply cannot wrap my head around. The question needs, I think, a little context so I will give that now:
Let L be a finite dimensional semisimple complex Lie Algebra and $\rho \colon L \to gl(V)$ a representation of L. Further let H be a Cartan Subalgebra of L. Then V has a decomposition consisting of eigenspaces of $\rho(H)$ of the form:
$$V = \bigoplus V_\lambda$$
where $V_\lambda$ is the weight space for elements of $\rho(H)$, and $\lambda \in H^*$. Further let $\Phi$ be the set of roots of $L$ w.r. to $H$ with base $\Delta$, and denote $L_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \Phi$ be the rootspace of $\alpha$ according to the usual root decomposition. Last, let $\{x_i, y_i, h_i\}$ be a set of standard generators according to the basis $\Delta$.
We call a vector $0 \neq v \in V_\lambda$ for some weight $\lambda$ of $V$ for which $x_i \cdot v =0$ for all $x_i$ a vector of heighest weight. Note that $\cdot$ means the induced module action. In the book, we now go ahead and consider for some heighest weight vector $v$ the set $W$ of all elements of the form:
$$y_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot y_{i_k} v$$
and show that this is indeed invariant under all $x_i, y_i, h_i$. That implies that $W$ is a submodule of $V$. Assume now that $V$ is an irreducible $L$ module. Then it follows that $W=V$, so far so good, but that means that every vector can be represented as such a term.
Now comes my problem, the book then states that this implies that there is up to nonzero complex scaling only one vector of highest weight. I cannot seem to get why, given our definition. Of course if we head two heighest weight vectors $v_1, v_2$, then we could write:
$$v_1 = y_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot y_{i_k} v_2$$
and it seems intuitive that $v_1$ then cannot be a vector of heighest weight, because we have that $v_1 \in V_{\lambda - \alpha_{i_1} - \dots - \alpha_{i_k}}$, where $\alpha_i$ are corresponding roots to the $y_i$. However, even though its clear that $x_j \cdot v_1 \in V_{\lambda - \alpha_{i_1} - \dots - \alpha_{i_k} + \alpha_j}$, I cannot figure out why this should be nonzero for sure for some $x_j$.
I think my question is closely related to the question what exactly $x_i, y_i$ do to some $v \in V_\lambda$. I know that:
$$x_i \cdot v \in V_{\lambda + \alpha_i}$$
$$y_i \cdot v \in V_{\lambda - \alpha_i}$$
but when could these be zero. Its clear they are zero when $\lambda + \alpha_i,\lambda - \alpha_i$ is not a weight, but must it be nonzero if it is a weight? If so, why?
I would be thankful for advice, as I have already spent hours on this little detail and it drives me nuts.
Edit: Since this was answered in very short time, I now would like to pose the second part of the question as the still open one. So the part of how $x_i,y_i$ act on weight spaces.

If there are two vectors of highest weight $v_1, v_2 \neq 0$, then by irreducibility we have to be able to write $v_1$ as a linear combination of elements of the form $y_{i_1} \dots y_{i_k} v_2$, and similarly we must be able to write $v_2$ as a similar linear combination of $y_{i_1} \dots y_{i_k} v_1$. Then we can substitute the formula for $v_2$ to write $v_1$ as a similar linear combination of elements of the form $y_{i_1} \dots y_{i_k} v_1$.
However, the action of $y_i$ always lowers the weight with respect to dominance order. This means that, unless the combinations do not actually involve the $y_i$ at all, $v_1$ lies in two different weight spaces, which is impossible. Hence all of the relations we wrote must not involve the $y_i$, so we must have $v_1 = \lambda v_2$ for some scalar $\lambda$.
For the second part, it can happen that $x \cdot v = 0$ for $x \in L_\alpha$, $v \in V_\lambda$ even if $\alpha + \lambda$ is a weight of the space. To construct an example, find an irreducible representation $V$ such that $\dim V_{\lambda} > \dim V_{\lambda + \alpha} > 0$ for some weight $\lambda$ and (simple) root $\alpha$. The adjoint representation $V = L$ of $L = \mathfrak{sl}_3$ is an easy example of such a representation. The $0$-weight space is just the Cartan subalgebra $V_0 = H$, which is $2$-dimensional, and for any root we know from general structure theory that $\dim L_{\alpha} = \dim V_\alpha = 1$. Consequently, the kernel of the map $\mathrm{ad}_{x_\alpha} : V_0 \to V_{\alpha}$ is nontrivial for dimension reasons, despite the fact that $V_\alpha$ is a nonzero weight space. The same phenomenon happens for the adjoint representation of any semisimple Lie algebra of rank at least $2$.
You might also ask whether the map $x: V_\lambda \to V_{\lambda + \alpha}$ is at least nonzero if $\lambda$ and $\lambda + \alpha$ are both weights, if not injective. This turns out to be true, and you can prove it by using $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-rep theory, analyzing $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} V_{\lambda + n\alpha}$ under the action of $\langle x_{\alpha}, h_{\alpha}, y_{\alpha}\rangle \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2$. I'll leave this as an exercise.

Oh my god, thank you so much, this bothered me a lot. Since this is true now, can you elaborate on the second part of the question, about the actions of x,y on weight spaces?

I've updated my answer to address your second question.

Thank you, I will no try to figure out the exercise.

Can you give me a hint for the exercise, I tried looking at your module, and at its decomposition into irreducible submodules, but I cant seem to find the reason why the map is not zero.

I think I just proved that this is equivalent to the statement: Any vector of highest weight belongs to a highest weight. However, I do not know that the second part is true. Please help me out here.

Could you please give me a hint for the exercise?

@Goldstern420 Do you know how to visualize $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representations with a weight diagram?

No, is there a way to prove it without it? I tried a lot of approaches but I always got stuck with questions regarding the amount of weights in the irreducible decomposition.

Could you please give me more hints, this seems really important but I cannot find it anywhere.

Do I need the module to be irreducible in order for this to work?
